# How to find a latest data in array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a conversation model like below:

```
const ConvoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    convoId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    seller: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    buyer: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    product: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
    messages: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' }]
})
```

and I'm trying to get latest message in the Convo but couldn't figure out how to do it. any ideas?

Comment: Unless you specifically modify adding items to the array with `$position` or `$sort` modifiers to `$push`, then the "latest" is always the "last" item, because adding new array entries "appends" to the end. Therefore you can always obtain the "latest" entry using [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) in projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_id` basically contains the timestamp in it, so the first element that you get in `.find()` will be the **oldest** and the last element will be **newest**,

so by adding a sort like: `{ _id: -1}` will give u the latest data

```
var Convo = mongoose.model('Convo', ConvoSchema); //init mongoose model

Convo.find()
     .limit(1)
     .sort({ _id: -1 })
```

you can remove the `.limit()` if u want complete list of documents

=======================================================================

Sorry for not reading it properly,

For Latest message,

```
Convo.findOne({}, response => {
   var data = response.toObject();
   latestMessage = data.messages.pop()
})
```

Comment: Question asks for last item in the "messages array" (*" trying to get latest message"* ). You are returning the last "document" and not the last item in the array "within the document".

Comment: just use the ```.pop()``` on the messages array. or ```data.messages[ data.messages.length - 1 ]``` will give u the correct result as well.

Comment: also make sure to use ```.toObject()``` to clone the model to a static object, so if in case u are using ```.save()``` to save the model in the same invocation. u don accidentally remove the latest message using ```.pop()```